# How do I add items to this shopping list

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get this code to work but I can't figure out why. I need what I type to be added to the list as an item.

I'm aware there's better ways of achieving this result but I'm trying to understand the fundamentals. Please explain what I'm doing wrong using my variables below:

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];


button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // create a list item
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    // create text node 
    const liText = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    
    //append text to li: <li> input value </li>
    let newLi = li.appendChild(liText);
    
    //append li to ul
    let newList = ul.appendChild(newLi);

    return newList;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Shopping List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <h2>Get it done today</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button>Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> The returned value (of `appendChild`) is the appended child

Which means that when you append to `ul` the `newLi` you actually append the text node `liText`, and not the `li` element. That's why you don't see it as a list item.

Just use the li instead like this:

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];


button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // create a list item
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  // create text node 
  const liText = document.createTextNode(input.value);

  //append text to li: <li> input value </li>
  li.appendChild(liText);

  //append li to ul
  let newList = ul.appendChild(li);

  return newList;
});
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<h2>Get it done today</h2>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button>Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li>Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Omri
Does that mean that I should not really ever use appendChild when saving values in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Append your `li`, not the result of `appendChild()` to the `ul`.

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];


button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // create a list item
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    // create text node 
    const liText = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    
    //append text to li: <li> input value </li>
    li.appendChild(liText);
    
    //append li to ul
    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Shopping List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <h2>Get it done today</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button>Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Another way would be:

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];


button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // create a list item
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    
    //append text to li: <li> input value </li>
    li.textContent = input.value;
  
    //append li to ul
    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Shopping List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <h2>Get it done today</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button>Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to return `newList` or even declare the variable in the first place.

Comment: @RickardElimää You're totally right. Not necessary as well. I removed it from my answer.